# Help with an integral involving the incomplete gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

We have the integral :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-h}\gamma(h,ax)\log(1+x)dx$$
where $\gamma(h,ax)$ is the lower incomplete gamma function, and the parameters $h,a$ are real. I have tried integrating by parts, but in vain. And i have tried using the series expansion of the incomplete gamma function, but the result is extremely complicated, and i doubt that the resulting series converges ! hence the thread. Any help is highly appreciated.